# STDERR output is not being captured when running invalid command

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am trying to catch the output from running the command `/bin/lsx -lah /`.

The output should be: `bash: /bin/lsx: no such file or directory`

However, I am just not getting anything in the `printf()`.

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define die(e) do { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

int main() {
  int link[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char foo[4096];

  if (pipe(link)==-1)
    die("pipe");

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    die("fork");

  if(pid == 0) {

    dup2 (link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(link[0]);
    close(link[1]);
    execl("/bin/lsx", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);
    die("execl");

  } else {

    close(link[1]);
    int nbytes = read(link[0], foo, sizeof(foo));
    printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", nbytes, foo);
    wait(NULL);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am just wondering why the output is not being captured and printed in the bottom `printf()`.

Comment: Commads generally produce error output to standard error, but you are redirecting (only) the command's standard output.  If you want both, then create a second pipe for standard error, OR make the command's standard error a dupe of its standard output.

Comment: Explain why you close both end of the pipe.

Comment: @Cheatah After `dup2`, the file descriptor usually associated with the standard output of the program now references the same file description the write end of the pipe references. It is common, and safe, to release the write end of the pipe's file descriptor after this operation.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a second pipe or make the command's standard error a dupe of its standard output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John pointed out, you are only capturing `stdout`, not `stderr`, and well-formed programs usually send error messages to `stderr` (the `die` macro you have shown is an example of this).

A quick solution is to redirect the child processes' `stderr` to its `stdout` with another call to `dup2`

```
dup2(link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
```

which will redirect both output streams to the single pipe.

Alternatively, capture both streams with two pipes to retain their separation as they propagate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define die(e) do { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

ssize_t push_through(const char *prefix,
        FILE *out, int in,
        char *buf, size_t bufsz)
{
    ssize_t bytes = read(in, buf, bufsz);

    if (bytes > 0)
        fprintf(out, "%s: (%.*s)\n", prefix, (int) bytes, buf);

    return bytes;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stdout_pipe[2];
    int stderr_pipe[2];
    char buffer[4096];

    if (pipe(stdout_pipe) == -1 || pipe(stderr_pipe) == -1)
        die("pipe");

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        die("fork");

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(stdout_pipe[0]);
        close(stderr_pipe[0]);

        dup2(stdout_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(stderr_pipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);

        close(stdout_pipe[1]);
        close(stderr_pipe[1]);

        execl("/bin/lsx", "ls", "-1", (char *) NULL);
        perror("execl failed because");
        die("execl");
    } else {
        ssize_t outbytes, errbytes;

        close(stdout_pipe[1]);
        close(stderr_pipe[1]);

        do {
            outbytes = push_through("out", stdout, stdout_pipe[0],
                    buffer, sizeof buffer);
            errbytes = push_through("err", stderr, stderr_pipe[0],
                    buffer, sizeof buffer);
        } while (outbytes > 0 || errbytes > 0);

        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

In the event that `execl` fails, it might be useful to call `perror` to print a more detailed error message.

Note that expecting the error

```
bash: /bin/lsx: no such file or directory
```

is possibly misguided, as `exec*` functions only defer to a shell under certain conditions.

The only mention of a shell in [`man 3 exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) is with regards to `execlp`, `execvp`, and `execvpe`:

> If the header of a file isn't recognized (the attempted execve(2)
> failed with the error ENOEXEC), these functions will execute the
> shell (/bin/sh) with the path of the file as its first argument.
> (If this attempt fails, no further searching is done.)

Comment: When running this, I am not getting the error in buffer. Is it because the application "lsx" doesn't exist so it cannot capture stderr?

Comment: @xf9000 I have added some more details.

Comment: Interesting. I think that is where I got confused. I was duping the pipe correctly I think but I just was not getting that output that I was hoping for. If it is just the nature of the functions then I will just use the return code from ```exec*``` to determine if the file was not found. Then the stderr buffer would hold the error message from the command if it was found and ran with invalid arguments, example ```ls -asdf```. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: Yes, pretty much (although `-asdf` are all valid flags for a typical `ls` :)). You can check / save the value of `errno` (`#include <errno.h>`) after the `exec*` call as well for more error handling control, as `exec*` simply return `-1` on failure, which alone does not tell you what kind of failure occurred.